# Array Formula (i.e., CSE) UDFs Called Twice

Tags: excel-dna

We've noticed that when the user enters an array formula (the legacy CSE formulas) for a UDF, the UDF is called twice. This does not happen with dynamic arrays (Excel 365+). This "double call" happens in Excel 2019 and 365.

Because this double call wreaks havoc with our validation code, we'd like to guard against it. Is there a way to detect an incoming CSE formula?

Comment: That's not expected for a simple array function that used from a CSE formula. Is it perhaps using the RTD-based async mechanism, or the 'Resizer' helper?

Comment: Yes, the CSE uses ExcelAsyncFunction. Is it the case then that we cannot use CSEs with ExcelAsyncFunction?